# What is area of circle given areas of $4$ squares

Tags: geometry, circles, area

[image: ?]

I can't find a way to solve this, I know that by using power of the point the other square area is 64cm^2 and that its side length is 8, but for the area of the circle I'm not too sure where to start, can someone help?

Comment: Draw the quadrilateral $ABCD$.  You have all four sides and know it is cyclic with perpendicular diagonals.

Comment: This site is not a drive-by solution-providing service, particular to contest questions.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

The area of the triangle $ABC$ is

$$Area_{ABC} = \frac 12 BX\cdot AC = \frac12 \cdot 5\cdot (4+10) = 35$$

Then, the circumradius of $ABC$ is,

$$R = \frac{AB\cdot BC\cdot CA}{4Area_{ABC}}
=\frac{\sqrt{4^2+5^2}\cdot \sqrt{10^2+5^2}\cdot 14}{4\cdot35}
=\frac{\sqrt{205}}{2}$$

Thus, the area of the circle is

$$Area_{circle} = \pi R^2= \frac{205\pi}4$$

Answer (score 3):

Let $X$ be the intersection point.

**Hint:** Recall that $4 \times 10 = Pow(X) = R^2 - d^2 $.

> Let $X = (0,0)$.
>  The center of the circle is $( -1.5, -3)$, so we can find $d^2$, so we can find $R^2$

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I added a coordinate system to the picture.

- Line $\overleftrightarrow{OG}$ is the perpendicular bisector of chord $\overline{AC}$.
- Line $\overleftrightarrow{OF}$ is the perpendicular bisector of chord $\overline{BD}$.
- Point $O$, the intersection of lines $\overleftrightarrow{OG}$ and $\overleftrightarrow{OF}$ is the center of the circle.

Find the coordinates of point $O$ and the measures of one of the distances to point $A$, $B$, $C$, or $D$. That will give you the radius of the circle.